# Undefined values in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

So I am trying to store an array of objects into localStorage, as follows:-

EDIT: The following is part of a function that is called in a loop.

```
c = [{"name":nameDOM.value,"add":+addDOM.value,"town":townDOM.value,"post":postalDOM.value,"mob":mobDOM.value}];
cData = cData.concat(c);
localStorage.setItem('cData', cData);
```

However, after a page refresh, when I try to access data from the objects, it is apparently undefined. Accessing data from the objects is fine before a refresh.

I am accessing the data in the following manner:-

```
//Table code omitted.
var text = document.createTextNode(""+cData[i].name+", "+cData[i].add+", "+cData[i].town+", "+cData[i].post+", "+cData[i].mob+"");
```

I have been trying to debug the problem using Chromes Javascript tools, as well as inserting alerts into various places to monitor the state of the variables; still undefined.

Comment: Could you give a not working example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i assume you are doing a getItem before actually using it right?

Comment: @NadirMuzaffar Yes, this is one of the first things that happens in the script. If it does not exist in localStorage, it is created. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made an oopsies. Try:

```
c = [{"name":nameDOM.value,"add":+addDOM.value,"town":townDOM.value,"post":postalDOM.value,"mob":mobDOM.value}];
cData = cData.concat(c);
localStorage.setItem('cData', JSON.stringify(cData));
```

They difference being that you are turning your array of objects into a json string that can be parsed later by your code using:

```
eval(localStorage.getItem('cData'));
```